# MySQL DB import fail of large file

Tags: mysql, sql, import, configuration

I have a problem with my local MySQL database. I use docker compose and run the database as follows:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database-shema'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - local-db:/home/jernej/dev/mysql/data
      - /home/jernej/dev/mysql:/etc/mysql/conf.d
# Names our volume
volumes:
  local-db:
```

As you can see, I use a configuration file on my local drive. In the directory mysql you can find the directory data and the configuration file my.cnf. The configuration looks like the following:

```
# Other default tuning values
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# On Windows you should keep this file in the installation directory 
# of your server (e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y). To
# make sure the server reads the config file use the startup option 
# "--defaults-file". 
#
# To run the server from the command line, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# To install the server as a Windows service manually, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# And then execute this in a command line shell to start the server, e.g.
# net start MySQLXY
#
#
# Guidelines for editing this file
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that the program supports.
# If you want to know the options a program supports, start the program
# with the "--help" option.
#
# More detailed information about the individual options can also be
# found in the manual.
#
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
#
#
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

# pipe=

# socket=MYSQL

[mysql]
no-beep

# default-character-set=


# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
# server_type=3
[mysqld]


# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=mysql=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
# port=3306

# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
# basedir=/usr/mysql

# Path to the database root
# datadir=/usr/mysql

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
# character-set-server=

# The default authentication plugin to be used when connecting to the server
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# General and Slow logging.
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="TEST.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="TEST-slow.log"
long_query_time=10

# Binary Logging.
# log-bin

# Error Logging.
log-error="TEST.err"

# Server Id.
server-id=1

# Secure File Priv.
# secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=150

# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value
# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.
# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files
# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in
# section [mysqld_safe]
table_open_cache=2000

# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=16M

# How many threads we should keep in a cache for reuse. When a client
# disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there aren't
# more than thread_cache_size threads from before.  This greatly reduces
# the amount of thread creations needed if you have a lot of new
# connections. (Normally this doesn't give a notable performance
# improvement if you have a good thread implementation.)
thread_cache_size=10

#*** MyISAM Specific options
# The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
# recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
# If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
# through the key cache (which is slower).
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

# If the temporary file used for fast index creation would be bigger
# than using the key cache by the amount specified here, then prefer the
# key cache method.  This is mainly used to force long character keys in
# large tables to use the slower key cache method to create the index.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M

# Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
# Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
# is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
# MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
# used for internal temporary disk tables.
key_buffer_size=8M

# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.
read_buffer_size=0

read_rnd_buffer_size=0

#*** INNODB Specific options ***
# innodb_data_home_dir=

# Use this option if you have a MySQL server with InnoDB support enabled
# but you do not plan to use it. This will save memory and disk space
# and speed up some things.
# skip-innodb

# If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
# disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
# willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
# transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
# logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
# the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
# means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
# file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# The size of the buffer InnoDB uses for buffering log data. As soon as
# it is full, InnoDB will have to flush it to disk. As it is flushed
# once per second anyway, it does not make sense to have it very large
# (even with long transactions).
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G

# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G

# Size of each log file in a log group. You should set the combined size
# of log files to about 25%-100% of your buffer pool size to avoid
# unneeded buffer pool flush activity on log file overwrite. However,
# note that a larger logfile size will increase the time needed for the
# recovery process.
innodb_log_file_size=3G

# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel. The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=17

# The increment size (in MB) for extending the size of an auto-extend InnoDB system tablespace file when it becomes full.
innodb_autoextend_increment=64

# The number of regions that the InnoDB buffer pool is divided into.
# For systems with buffer pools in the multi-gigabyte range, dividing the buffer pool into separate instances can improve concurrency,
# by reducing contention as different threads read and write to cached pages.
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

# Determines the number of threads that can enter InnoDB concurrently.
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

# Specifies how long in milliseconds (ms) a block inserted into the old sublist must stay there after its first access before
# it can be moved to the new sublist.
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

# It specifies the maximum number of .ibd files that MySQL can keep open at one time. The minimum value is 10.
innodb_open_files=300

# When this variable is enabled, InnoDB updates statistics during metadata statements.
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

# When innodb_file_per_table is enabled (the default in 5.6.6 and higher), InnoDB stores the data and indexes for each newly created table
# in a separate .ibd file, rather than in the system tablespace.
innodb_file_per_table=1

# Use the following list of values: 0 for crc32, 1 for strict_crc32, 2 for innodb, 3 for strict_innodb, 4 for none, 5 for strict_none.
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

# The number of outstanding connection requests MySQL can have.
# This option is useful when the main MySQL thread gets many connection requests in a very short time.
# It then takes some time (although very little) for the main thread to check the connection and start a new thread.
# The back_log value indicates how many requests can be stacked during this short time before MySQL momentarily
# stops answering new requests.
# You need to increase this only if you expect a large number of connections in a short period of time.
back_log=80

# If this is set to a nonzero value, all tables are closed every flush_time seconds to free up resources and
# synchronize unflushed data to disk.
# This option is best used only on systems with minimal resources.
flush_time=0

# The minimum size of the buffer that is used for plain index scans, range index scans, and joins that do not use
# indexes and thus perform full table scans.
join_buffer_size=256K

# The maximum size of one packet or any generated or intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the
# mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function.
max_allowed_packet=4M

# If more than this many successive connection requests from a host are interrupted without a successful connection,
# the server blocks that host from performing further connections.
max_connect_errors=100

# Changes the number of file descriptors available to mysqld.
# You should try increasing the value of this option if mysqld gives you the error "Too many open files".
open_files_limit=4161

# If you see many sort_merge_passes per second in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output, you can consider increasing the
# sort_buffer_size value to speed up ORDER BY or GROUP BY operations that cannot be improved with query optimization
# or improved indexing.
sort_buffer_size=256K

# The number of table definitions (from .frm files) that can be stored in the definition cache.
# If you use a large number of tables, you can create a large table definition cache to speed up opening of tables.
# The table definition cache takes less space and does not use file descriptors, unlike the normal table cache.
# The minimum and default values are both 400.
table_definition_cache=1400

# Specify the maximum size of a row-based binary log event, in bytes.
# Rows are grouped into events smaller than this size if possible. The value should be a multiple of 256.
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replication slave synchronizes its master.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_master_info events.
sync_master_info=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, the MySQL server synchronizes its relay log to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log writes to the relay log.
sync_relay_log=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replication slave synchronizes its relay-log.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log_info transactions.
sync_relay_log_info=10000

# Load mysql plugins at start."plugin_x ; plugin_y".
# plugin_load

# MySQL server's plugin configuration.
# loose_mysqlx_port=33060

innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
max_allowed_packet=512M
wait_timeout=30000
```

Now the DB dump I am trying to import is really big. The SQL file is about 12,9 GB big. Everytime I log into mysql console and run `source ~/Downloads/db-dump.sql`, I get an error after a while `ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 8982: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. As suggested by google, I also added the configuration `net_read_timeout` and `connect_timeout` as suggested here https://anothercoffee.net/fix-error-code-2013-lost-connection-mysql-server-query/. But that did not help at all. In my last attempt to run DB dump I use an empty configuration file. I am able to import everything, when the configuration is empty like this:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Any idea what configuration could trigger this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change 1 to this things.

1. change the **max_allowed_packet=4M** to a higher value
   This value means how long is the maximum lenght of one statement

or

2. generate a new dump from your Database and change this before

   - add --max_allowed_packet=512M to your mysqldump command.
   - or add max_allowed_packet=512M to [mysqldump] section of your my.cnf.

Comment: I looked up what you wrote. I see I have `max_allowed_packet` listed and set twice in the same configuration file. Can I assume this would mean it only takes the first (first occurrence from top to bottom) value set in the file?

Comment: Query set value with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'max%'; then you can see with one is taken

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` returns 536870912. Converting from bytes to megabytes is 512MB. Therefore it does take the second value being set. I assume then it is something else. I will of course double check by running the SQL again.

Comment: Set for test to 1G a d import again.

Comment: I will try that, but the default value is 64MB (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). I would assume it does not work.

Comment: I tried it with 1GB @bernd-buffen (verified it in the console with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`, but it fails again. So my assumption was correct. It has to be another value that causes this issue.

Comment: If you could post to pastebin.com A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; from the failing run and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; from the successful run, we will be able to compare the two and point you to the specific cause of the failure, please. read_buffer_size=0 and read_rnd_buffer_size=0 would never be a good thing, remove but do not remove them yet.  After the failure, could you FLUSH LOGS; and post the last 400 lines of your error log?

Comment: Here is the whole configuration pasted @WilsonHauck - [failure](https://pastebin.com/y7XhjBtP), [success](https://pastebin.com/uF2qf59K)

Comment: Please post on pastebin.com from LX command prompt A) df -h to verify free available space.  myisam_max_sort_file_size is asking for ~ 100G.  With a 13G CSV going in this probably should be reduced.  B) What is the RAM size on the MySQL server?

Comment: C) How many rows do you expect to have in the table when finished?  D) Going to MyISAM or INNODB engine?

Comment: So the df -h returned 93G available @WilsonHauck. And I run MySQL with 16GB, but I never get near 13 GB.

In regards to the row number, probably in the space of million records, since booking holds a lot of records.

Comment: Can you create a new dumpfile?

Comment: Have you restore a dumpfile before?

Comment: Could you post text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (yourtablename); for an awareness of your columns, indexes, engine and maybe next auto increment number?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I am not the one creating a dumpfile. I just download the script, which is yipped as well, since the file is huge. In the worst case scenario I can iterate through all the configuration and try to eliminate the setting responsible for the failure. Please correct me if I am wrong, but since empty (default) configuration successfully imports, I should be able to assume it is a specific configuration value that differs from the default.

Comment: @WilsonHauck here is the booking table https://pastebin.com/E6vyeirs

Comment: Is the sql file a public file so rhat i can also download and test it ?

Comment: Thank you for your postings.  A previous appointment - out of the office - will occupy my next 4 hours.  Will try to get Answer with suggestions posted before the end of the day.

Comment: @BerndBuffen there is no way to download it. It also contains sensitive data, therefore I couldn't share it in the first place.

Comment: @Jernej K - i am working over 25 years with MySQL / MariaDB and sometimes this error occurs. can we have a telefone call or whatsapp call. in my profile is my e-mail and phonenumber. if you want to have a whatsapp call send me a short email. then i will send you my mobile number. After this we can put the results in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 8192
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 1 - do not know how this could survive
innodb_thread_sleep_delay=10000  #  for the default 
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=20000  # from 150000 for 2 second delay when busy
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from 12G
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU busy significantly.

For additional assistance, view my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Comment: @Jernej K  Try your import with these settings, please and let me know if you were successful.